# Using cURL to login into websites

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I have a working cURL code, and I already tested it on my own website, and it works, so now I'm trying to test it on other websites, to make sure it also works too. I tested it on stackoverflow, but it returned unexpected results. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f');
$post_params = array('email' => 'frosty1234@mail.com', 'password' => 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params); // PHP will format the array into POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

**Result:**

```
Object moved to here.
```

^---clicking on here, brings me to stackoverflow's main page. However, I'm not logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what makes you think SO accepts post parameters to login?

Comment: @Sebas Um, I don't know? I'm new to all this. Is there a way to tell for sure if a website allows it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's working, you just have to tell curl to follow the redirect:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

and possibly

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Do I put this after curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);?

Comment: It followed the redirect, and it went to stackoverflow's main page, but it doesn't show that I'm logged in.